# Sort List based on multiple properties Collection.sort() Compile error

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I need to sort a list using multiple properties, I tried this code but I am getting a compilation error

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;

@Log4j
public class TestSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Kot> kots = new ArrayList<Kot>(){{

            add(new Kot("aa",1));
            add(new Kot("vv",1));
            add(new Kot("zz",2));
            add(new Kot("bb",3));
            add(new Kot("cc",1));
        }};

        log.info(kots);
        Collections.sort(kots);
        log.info(kots);
    }
}

@Data
class Kot implements Comparator<Kot> {

    private String productName;
    private Integer kotNo;

    public Kot(){}

    public Kot(String productName,Integer kotNo){
        this.productName = productName;
        this.kotNo = kotNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Kot kot1, Kot kot2) {
        int kotNoCompare = kot1.kotNo.compareTo(kot2.kotNo);
        if (kotNoCompare == 0) {
            int productNameCompare = kot1.productName.compareTo(kot2.productName);
            return productNameCompare;
        }
        return kotNoCompare;
    }
}
```

Error showing in following line

`Collections.sort(kots);`

Error Saying that,

Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List). The inferred type Kot is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to implement `Comparable` Interface for this.
E.g:

```
class Kot implements Comparable<Kot> {

    private String productName;
    private Integer kotNo;

    public Kot() {
    }

    public Kot(String productName, Integer kotNo) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.kotNo = kotNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Kot kot1) {
        int kotNoCompare = kot1.kotNo.compareTo(this.kotNo);
        if (kotNoCompare == 0) {
            int productNameCompare = kot1.productName.compareTo(this.productName);
            return productNameCompare;
        }
        return kotNoCompare;
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Comparator` only, then you have to move that comparison logic into a separate class. `Kot` will remain a simple POJO class, containing only getter and setters.

E.g of `Comparataor` only logic:

```
class Comp implements Comparator<Kot>{
     @Override
        public int compare(Kot kot1, Kot kot2) {
            int kotNoCompare = kot1.getKotNo().compareTo(kot2.getKotNo());
            if (kotNoCompare == 0) {
                int productNameCompare = kot1.getProductName().compareTo(kot2.getProductName());
                return productNameCompare;
            }
            return kotNoCompare;
        }
}
```

Now to sort your list, you can use other method of sorting:

```
Collections.sort(kots, new Comp());
```

Answer (score 2):

You made your `Kot` a `Comparator` of `Kot`s. However, `sort()` method expects `Kot` to be `Comparable` to other `Kot`s:

```
class Kot implements Comparable<Kot> {
    ...
    public int compareTo(Kot otherKot) {
        // Comparison logic needs to be transformed
        // to compare otherKot to this, rather than kot1 to kot2
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also split your class into `Kot` and `KotComparator`, move comparator logic into `KotComparator`, and use `sort()` overload that takes a custom comparator to do sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to sort

- First with `kotNo`
- Then with `productName`

Actually this `Comparable` thing is an age old one. With Java 8 all you need is only one line,

```
List<Kot> kots = new ArrayList<Kot>(){{
        add(new Kot("aa",1));
        add(new Kot("vv",1));
        add(new Kot("zz",2));
        add(new Kot("bb",3));
        add(new Kot("cc",1));
}};

kots = kots.stream().sorted(
                comparing(Kot::getKotNo)
                .thenComparing(comparing(Kot::getProductName)))
                .collect(toList());
```